# how to reuse the area in a container when any component is removed from it?

Tags: java, swing

i hav a panel and i m trying to remove labels from it which were added to it during run-time.
but when labels are removed succesfully i m not able to use the space,left by that label,again to add any label to it.

thanks in anticipation of the solution.

here is the relevant code snippet:

1. to add label to the panel:

   ```
   JLabel jl = new JLabel();
   jl.setOpaque(true);
   jl.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:/Project/router2.jpg"));
   jl.setBounds(x, y, jl.getPreferredSize().width,
       jl.getPreferredSize().height);
   for (Component c : lcomponent) {
       flag = true;
       Rectangle r4 = c.getBounds();
       int x1 = (int) r4.getX();
       int y1 = (int) r4.getY();
       Rectangle r5 = new Rectangle(
           new Point(x1 - 60, y1 - 60), new Dimension(170, 170));
       if (r5.contains(p)) { //To ensure that two labels do not overlap
           flag = false;     //or are too close to each other
           break;
       }
   }
   if (flag) {
       p2.add(jl); //p2 is a panel
       Component c2 = p2.getComponentAt(x, y);
       p2.repaint();
       lcomponent.add(c2); //lcomponent is an ArrayList<Component> to
                           //store all the labels added to the panel
   }
   ```
2. to remove the label:

   ```
   p2.remove(<label name>);
   p2.repaint();
   ```

i hav tried revalidate() also but i dont know why it automatically aligns the components in
a row at the top.

help me with this also

Comment: I have reformatted your code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Call Container.invalidate()

Comment: I just realized you are positioning your labels but you don't say anything about the container's layout. It looks like you have a layout manager, call Container.setLayout(null) to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

After adding/removing components from a visible frame you should use:

```
//panel.add(...);
panel.remove(...);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

Comment: i tried revalidate() but it aligned the components at the top in a row

Comment: Thats correct. That is the way layout managers work. The default layout manager for a JPanel is the FlowLayout which lays out components in a row. If you are trying to achieve some other layout then you need to use different layout managers. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on Using Layout Managers: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html. You may think it is simpler to not use a layout manager at first, but you will always encounter problems later if you don't.

Comment: ok thats correct.but i m trying to add components at random locations.
i dont think u can use any layout manager for this,it has to be set to null.

Answer (score 0):

i think i got the answer.actually while removing the component,i was removing it from the panel but not from the arraylists(lcomponent and label above) because of which i was not able to use that area again to put any other component.removing the entry from lists worked for me.